# ANDROID FRAGMENT GOOGLE MAPS V2 ERROR,FOLLOWED ANDROID HIVE TUTORIAL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

raks  here ,please resolve this is problem,thank you in advance ,i followed this tutoriall,***http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/***

in activity_main i have changed android:name attribute inside fragment from android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

and also in my manifestfile/application i have added this

below is the error iam getting

```
11-22 11:49:38.948: D/AndroidRuntime(2877): Shutting down VM
11-22 11:49:38.948: W/dalvikvm(2877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41706d40)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): Process: com.example.googlemapdemo, PID: 2877
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapdemo/com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     ... 11 more
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4795)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     ... 21 more
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
11-22 11:49:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(2877):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: can you please post activity code ?

Comment: seems you are missing support library.
You better get sample of maps from sdk which is best sample of maps. just replace api key in menifest.

Comment: sir md , i have imported play lib , i have installed everything no compilation errors

Comment: hi harish this is simple code  ,i am using code from android hive google map v2 , please can you check it once